# Swipe menu nav cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I make my first app with cordova/Angularjs.

I trying to do a swipe menu nav like the YouTube app, Tinder app etc. 
Who when you swipe, the menu follow your finger. 
Not the simply swipe.

Is it possible with angular without Jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like option you can use [Onsen.io](http://onsen.io/) is a framework runing in AngularJS pretty fast.

```
<ons-sliding-menu var="app.menu" main-page="page.html" menu-page="menu.html" max-slide-distance="200px" type="reveal" side="left">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="page.html">
  <ons-page>
   <p style="text-align: center">
     <ons-button ng-click="app.menu.toggleMenu()">Toggle</ons-button>
   </p>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-page>
    <!-- menu page's contents -->
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Look your example: [Sliding Menu](http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/IDvFJ)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted ! Thanks !